# Device trips GFCI on one outlet, but when plugged into a different GFCI it works

Tags: electrical

Ok, I have a 120v fuel pump on a diesel transfer tank, that when plugged in to a particular GFCI outlet it trips the GFCI as soon as I turn it on. But it I get a 20' extension cord and plug it in to a different GFCI (about 10' away it works fine. Both outlets are 20 amp, and I just replaced the tripping GFCI with a new 20 amp one. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a GFCI tester plug?  Maybe the one that doesn't trip is bad.  Maybe its just old and not as sensitive as it should be?

Comment: The 20' extension cord adds resistance, which will lower the peak current surge a bit.  You are changing 2 variables at once - That's not how to run an experiment  ;)   Try plugging the long extension cord setup into the close-by outlet and see if behaves differently.       And ^^^ is right, you might have a bad outlet.

Comment: Does the extension cord have a functioning ground wire/pin?  Deleting ground prevents fault current from returning easily, which can **mask** the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try plugging your transfer pump into your 20' extension cord and then plug it into the first GFCI.  Maybe you're running into two issues, something with the fuel pump wiring, and a broken ground wire on your extension cord.

Comment: Brilliant! Good check of the extension cord.

Comment: Good Idea! I actually did that yesterday, and it worked when plugged into the new GFCI via an extension cord. I pulled the cover off the wiring of the pump and there seems to be a lot of condensation in it--wet wires. The pump is getting old anyway, so I'll be replacing it tomorrow. BTW, this pump worked in this outlet a couple of months ago. So I'm pretty sure the problem is moisture in the wiring.